# Why React Component renders twice

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
const fetchRequest = useCallback( () => {
        setIsLoading( true );
        axios( {
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://bouvet.guru/rekrytering_flera.php"
        } ).then( ( response ) => {
            if ( response.data.indexOf( "https://" ) !== -1 ) {
                let splittedArray = response.data.split( "Data:" );
                let dataString = splittedArray[1];

                if ( dataString.includes( "<URL kommentar>" ) ) {

                    dataString.substring( 16 );
                    let pairedData = dataString.split( "http" );
                    pairedData.splice( 0, 1 );

                    const finalArray = pairedData.map( ( group ) => {
                        const url = group.split( " " )[0];
                        const comment = group.replace( url, "" );

                        // Return an object with the paired properties. ID is not optimal to be Math.random(), this is for demonstration purpose.
                        return { url: "http" + url, comment, id: Math.random() };

                    } );

                    setData( [ ...data, ...finalArray ] );
                    setIsLoading( false );
                } else {
                    console.log( "NOPE" );
                }
            } else {
                console.log( "We could not find any data" );
                setIsLoading( false );
            }
        } );
    }, [] );

    useEffect( () => {
        fetchRequest();
        setInterval( () => {
            fetchRequest();
        }, 30000 );
    }, [] );


    console.log( data );
```

It's just a simple useEffect axios call in which I receive a string, which I then set as state, and then just log this to the console afterwards.

I always get 2 arrays of the same.

(I know it now is a useCallback, but had the same issue when It was only a useEffect in the entire code.

This component is on its own.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567640/use-setinterval-in-react/58567676#58567676 might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
const fetchRequest = () => {
        setIsLoading( true );
        axios( {
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://bouvet.guru/rekrytering_flera.php"
        } ).then( ( response ) => {
            if ( response.data.indexOf( "https://" ) !== -1 ) {
                let splittedArray = response.data.split( "Data:" );
                let dataString = splittedArray[1];

                if ( dataString.includes( "<URL kommentar>" ) ) {

                    dataString.substring( 16 );
                    let pairedData = dataString.split( "http" );
                    pairedData.splice( 0, 1 );

                    const finalArray = pairedData.map( ( group ) => {
                        const url = group.split( " " )[0];
                        const comment = group.replace( url, "" );

                        // Return an object with the paired properties. ID is not optimal to be Math.random(), this is for demonstration purpose.
                        return { url: "http" + url, comment, id: Math.random() };

                    } );

                    setData( [ ...data, ...finalArray ] );
                    setIsLoading( false );
                } else {
                    console.log( "NOPE" );
                }
            } else {
                console.log( "We could not find any data" );
                setIsLoading( false );
            }
        } );
    };

    useEffect( () => {
        fetchRequest();
        const interval = setInterval( () => {
            fetchRequest();
        }, 30000 );
        return ()=>{clearInterval(interval);}
    }, [] );


    console.log( data );
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely 2nd render is triggered by `setIsLoading( false )`

Comment: I thought so as well, but it does the same thing when i removed everything about ```setIsLoading```

Comment: Well then more information is needed. 2 things that usually trigger re-render are state and props change. Also temporary removing setInterval call might help to investigate further.

Comment: Also I'd advice adding more debug logging, for example add log before you call `axios(...)`